# How do I associate the Enter key with a button on an ascx page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a button on one of my content pages which i need to fire on hitting the enter button. I tried specifying the default button in the updatepanel but without any avail. If you have a solution for the same please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not write **"please let me know"**. This site was created to **let each other know**. So, if anybody can help you, he or she will help.

Comment: Nigh duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350655/how-do-i-associate-the-enter-key-with-a-button-on-an-aspx-page

Comment: [Duplicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350655/how-do-i-associate-the-enter-key-with-a-button-on-an-aspx-page

Answer (score 4):

Use the panel control and setup your button with `DefaultButton="Button1"`

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
 .................................
 ...............your contents..................
 </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use javascript, which you can call from the textbox's key press event,

```
function checkKey(b1, e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById(b1).click();
    return false;
}    }
```

Hope this will helps...